# clonezilla as an option in a grub menu

Tags: boot, grub2, clonezilla

I'm trying to insert a clonezilla-live option into my Ubuntu grub menu. I put the Clonezilla .iso file in the root directory and then updated the
`/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file with the following entry:

menuentry "Clonezilla live" {
set isofile="/clonezilla-live-3.0.3-22-amd64.iso"
loopback loop $isofile linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz boot=live union=overlay username=user config components quiet noswap nolocales edd=on nomodeset nodmraid ocs_live_run="ocs-live-general" ocs_live_extra_param="" keyboard-layouts= ocs_live_batch="no" locales= vga=788 ip=frommedia nosplash toram=filesystem.squashfs findiso=$isofile initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img }

I then ran `update-grub2`, rebooted and selected clonezilla-live from the grub menu. The clonezilla .iso file must have been found because a Clonezilla screen was displayed, but it was the "second screen" (utf-8 options) instead of the "first screen" (GNU GRUB menu with 800x600 options).

Comment: Interesting note here.  If I put the same clonezilla .iso file on a ventoy usb stick and boot up from it the first screen does shows up!  So why is clonezilla working as it should here but not when selected from the grub2?  krplun

Comment: I think it is a good idea to boot Clonezilla from a separate drive (typically a USB pendrive). This way Clonezilla's live system will be completely independent of the internal drive, and it is an advantage when making an image of the whole drive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clonezilla as an option on a grub2 boot menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464321/clonezilla-as-an-option-on-a-grub2-boot-menu)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times.