# Clonezilla as an option on a grub2 boot menu

Tags: boot, grub2, clonezilla

I'm trying to insert a clonezilla-live option into my Ubuntu grub menu. I'm trying to insert a clonezilla-live option into my Ubuntu grub menu. Is there anyone out there that is running a recent version (i.e. 3.0.3-22-amd64) of a clonezilla.iso file from a Linux PC grub2 boot menu? If so can you share your menu entry with me? I put the Clonezilla .iso file in the root directory and then updated the
`/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file with the following entry:

menuentry "Clonezilla live" {
set isofile="/clonezilla-live-3.0.3-22-amd64.iso"
loopback loop $isofile linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz boot=live union=overlay username=user config components quiet noswap nolocales edd=on nomodeset nodmraid ocs_live_run="ocs-live-general" ocs_live_extra_param="" keyboard-layouts= ocs_live_batch="no" locales= vga=788 ip=frommedia nosplash toram=filesystem.squashfs findiso=$isofile initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img }

When I select the clonezilla option from the grub2 boot menu what's suppose to get displayed first is the clonezilla GNU menu with the screen options on it (i.e. 800x600...), however that screen is bypassed and what does get displayed first is the second Clonezilla screen (i.. en_us.utf-8...). I have done a lot of research, but I can't seem to resolve this problem.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: Well it appears I have it partially working.  Clonezilla has it's own grub2 menu so I took the menuentry from that and put it into the 40_custom file and added the isofile entry parms .  When I reboot and select that entry it finds the clonezilla.iso file and does the backup unattended as I want.  What happens though is it backs up partition 1 (dev) and 2 (/boot/efi) sucessfully but ignores partition 3 (my filesystem).  I'm thinking maybe it's because that's where the clonezilla.iso file resides.  Does that make sense to anyone?  Thanks in advance...

Comment: menuentry "clonezilla" {
 gfxpayload=1024x768x16,1024x768
 set isofile="/ISO/clonezilla-live-2.7.2-39-amd64.iso"
 loopback loop (hd1,1)$isofile
 linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz nomodeset boot=live live-config edd=on ocs_live_run=\"ocs-live-general\" ocs_live_extra_param=\"\" keyboard-layouts=\"us\" ocs_live_batch=\"no\" locales=\"en_US.UTF-8\" ip=frommedia  toram=filesystem.squashfs findiso=$isofile
 initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
        }

Comment: I'm closing this ticket.  Verndog on liuxquestions.org shared his menuentry and it worked perfectly for me.   menuentry "clonezilla" {
 gfxpayload=1024x768x16,1024x768
 set isofile="/ISO/clonezilla-live-2.7.2-39-amd64.iso"
 loopback loop (hd1,1)$isofile
 linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz nomodeset boot=live live-config edd=on ocs_live_run=\"ocs-live-general\" ocs_live_extra_param=\"\" keyboard-layouts=\"us\" ocs_live_batch=\"no\" locales=\"en_US.UTF-8\" ip=frommedia  toram=filesystem.squashfs findiso=$isofile
 initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
        }